# Property Lambda expression gets an additional Convert(p=>p.Property)

Tags: c#, lambda

I have a problem where in some cases (appears to be where property type is bool) a lambda expression used to refer to a property. I use this to get its name; the problem is sometime the expression is getting modified to have an additional Convert() function.

e.g.

```
GetPropertyName<TSource>(Expression<Func<TSource, object>> propertyLambda) {...}

var str = GetPropertyName<MyObject>(o=>o.MyBooleanProperty);
```

What's happening it that the propertyLambda looks like `Convert(o.MyBooleanProperty)` and not `o.MyBooleanProperty` that i'd expect.

Comment: Sorry, what is the question exactly? Where does the ``Convert`` function come from?

Comment: Can we see GetPropertyName implementation code

Comment: Please see "[Stack Overflow does not allow tags in titles](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130208)".

Comment: ok thanks john. but part of the question was any ideas [why this is happening]? - as Philip mentioned it looks more like a statement without a question at the end. but appreciate your effort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Convert` is added, because `o.MyBooleanProperty` is a `bool`, but the result has to be an object. If you made your method generic both in the source object type and the result type, then there would be no `Convert`:

```
GetPropertyName<TSource, TResult>(Expression<Func<TSource, TResult>> propertyLambda)
```

Unfortunately this means you have to specify `TResult` explicitly:

```
GetPropertyName<MyObject, bool>(o => o.MyBooleanProperty)
```

If you don't want to do that, you would have to find some way to infer `MyObject`, or avoid needing it.

For example, if the current object is `MyObject` (and you're in an instance method), you could change your code to take `Func<TResult>`:

```
GetPropertyName(() => this.MyBooleanProperty)
```

Or you could include another parameter of type `TSource` that will help you infer the type:

```
GetPropertyName(myObject, o => o.MyBooleanProperty)
```

Comment: thanks a lot @svick - given your last example `GetPropertyName(myObject, o => o.MyBooleanProperty)` - what would the function declaration look like, i'd obviously need to add an object parameter?  also, would it be possible to create an extension that provides a GetPropertyName extension method base on this `GetPropertyName(() => this.MyBooleanProperty)` example?

Comment: The declaration for last option would look something like `GetPropertyName<TSource, TResult>(TSource obj, Expression<Func<TSource, TResult>> propertyLambda)`. And I'm not sure what do you mean by the extension method, in that option, you don't need any instance, it can be normal static method.